# Sticky drop down box issue in php

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to create a sticky drop down option box. but every time I click the submit button, the value doesn't carry over. It changes.

What am I doing wrong?

```
    <select name=person >
       <option value="NULL">Choose a person</option>';
    <?php $dbc = getDBC ();
          $result = $dbc->query('SELECT * from person');
          while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          echo "<option value=\"$row[ID]\"";
         if (isset($_POST['person']) && ($_POST['person'] == $row[ID])) {
          echo 'selected="selected"';
         }
    echo ">($row[ID]) &nbsp $row[FIRST_NAME] &nbsp $row[LAST_NAME]</option>\n";
      }   
      ?>
</select>
```

Comment: May not make a difference, but values of attributes should be quoted. _name=person_ should be _name='person'_. Have you tried echoing $_POST['person'] to verify that it is the right value?

Comment: I think the problem is in here. isset($_POST['person']) && ($_POST['person'] == $row[ID]). Does each variable by itself produce the desired output?

Comment: Also, your variables should have quotes. $row[ID] should be $row['ID'] same with LAST_NAME, and FIRST_NAME.

Comment: Does `$_POST['person']` indeed contain row ID?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code i made some syntax changes changes. and also you can optimize it using where condition `SELECT * from person where id = $_POST['person']`

```
<select name=person >
           <option value="NULL">Choose a person</option>';
           <?php 
                $dbc = getDBC ();
                $result = $dbc->query('SELECT * from person');
                while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<option value=\"$row['ID']\"";

                if (isset($_POST['person']) && $_POST['person'] == $row['ID']) {

                echo 'selected="selected"';
                }

                echo ">($row['ID']) &nbsp $row['FIRST_NAME'] &nbsp $row['LAST_NAME']</option>\n";

               }   

               ?>
           </select>
```

Comment: I tried the above code but it shows an error message. Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)